Overflow scrolling on dynamic sibling div
I have html markup
<div class="wrapper">
  <aside class="l-side">
    <div class="l-content"></div>
  </aside>
  <aside class="r-side">
    <div class="r-content"></div>
  </aside>
</div>

The .l-content div height is dynamic, depending on amount of data fetched and it extends the height of the .wrapper div.
The .r-content div has its height different from .l-content so when it is higher from .l-content then .r-content extend the height of the .wrapper.
What I need is to set overflow scroll on .r-content when the .r-content reaches the height defined by .l-content.
I've tried a lot of different approaches and non of them worked as expected.
Set all parents to overflow-y: hidden then .r-content overflow-y: auto or scroll.
Tried to calculate the .l-content height and give it to .r-content. Nothing worked.
